# How to get value of selected index in combo Box when user select the value from it in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flex3

Hi I have created a comboBox dynamically and Since I'm new to Flex I have no idea how to get the selected value from combo box when user select a value from combobox dropdown

Below is my code

```
var comboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.dataProvider = field.getValues();
comboBox.width = "50";
comboBox.prompt = "Test";
comboBox.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Could someone help me out in order to identify how I'll be able to get value of a selected index when user will select the value from dropdown of combo box ?

Even a sample example will help me !!

Thanks in Advance.....!!

Comment: I don't understand this question.  You already know about `selectedIndex`, isn't it obvious that you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like following way:

```
var comboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.dataProvider = field.getValues();
comboBox.width = 50;
comboBox.prompt = "Test";
comboBox.selectedIndex = -1;
comboBox.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE, onChange);
panel.addChild(comboBox);

private function onChange(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.currentTarget.selectedItem); //Here you get the selected item.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `comboBox.selectedItem`.

Remember to check for null as `selectedItem` will return null if it is not set.

```
comboBox.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE, comboBox_change, false, 0, true); //weak listener

private function comboBox_change(event:Event):void {
  var comboBox:ComboBox = event.target as ComboBox
  var item:MyClass = comboBox.selectedItem as MyClass
  if(item) {
    //do what you need to do
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error -1120: Access of undefined property ListEvent.